# How do I create a custom plugin?

Tags: 8, chaos-tool-suite, plugins

Basically, I want to port a custom ctools plugin created for content type from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. This is the code I want to port.

```
function my_module_ctools_plugin_directory($module, $plugin) {
  if (($module == 'ctools') && ($plugin == 'content_types')) {
    return 'plugins/content_types';
  }
}
```

In my_module/plugins/content_types/my_module.inc file i have following code:

```
/**
 * Plugin array() of ctools plugin.
 */
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('My Module'),
  'single' => TRUE,
  'content_types' => array('my_module_custom_content_type'),
  'render callback' => 'my_module_render',
  'required context' => new ctools_context_required(t('Node'), 'node'),
  'edit form' => 'my_module_settings_form',
  'edit form validation' => 'my_module_settings_form_submit',
  'category' => 'Widgets',
);

/**
 * Render callback function.
 */
function my_module_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $context) {
  $node = $context->data;
  if (empty($node)) {
    return;
  }
  $data = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('my_module_form', $context, $conf);
  $block = new stdClass();
  $block->content = $data;
  $block->title = '';
  $block->id = 'my_module_form';
  return $block;
}
```

How do I port the plugin to Drupal 8?

Answer (score 5):

There are no ctools plugins anymore in Drupal 8. There's just the Drupal 8 plugin API.

Page Manager, Panels and so on use standard block plugins now in 8.x, so you basically have to port this to a block an then it should work fine.

Also, the "code" you posted only defines that you have such a plugin in your module, nothing else. If you need more specific support, you will need to post your actual code, and ask specific questions (which are probably better as a follow-up question).

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you elaborate how to do it now. I know how to create block plugin in D8, but not sure of this scenario.

Comment: What exactly is "this scenario", that's still only the plugin definition. I can see it uses contexts, those are supported for Blocks too, see \Drupal\block_test\Plugin\Block\TestContextAwareBlock for an example that uses entity:user, yours would be entity:node. Otherwise that looks like standard block functionality to me, but I don't really know the 7.x API. If that's not it, then as written, create a new, specific question and make sure all relevant code is there

Comment: I have also update render_callback function. I guess plugins are replaced by blocks in D8 and those blocks can be added in panels. I thinks i have understood the working. Let me correct if i am wrong.